# Rotate UIImageView inside compass like iOS compass

Tags: rotation, imageview, compass

I would like to include in my application a compass and labels cardinal gravitationally rotate and maintain its position as the compass of iOS application.

[image: iOS 8 Compass]

I've done some code and separately running, but when they work together goes crazy.

This is part of the code I use:

UIImageView * imgCompass;
UIImageView * north;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.headingFilter = 1;
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01;
motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.01;

[motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                    withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData  *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                                        if (!error) {
                                            [self outputAccelertionData:accelerometerData.acceleration];
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                        }
                                    }];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {

    // Convert Degree to Radian and move the needle
    newRad =  -newHeading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        self.viewCompass.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad);

    } completion:nil];
}


- (void)outputAccelertionData:(CMAcceleration)acceleration{
    //UIInterfaceOrientation orientationNew;

    // Get the current device angle
    float xx = -acceleration.x;
    float yy = acceleration.y;
    float angle = atan2(yy, xx);


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        // Add 1.5 to the angle to keep the image constantly horizontal to the viewer.
        [self.north setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle - 1.5)];
    } completion:nil];


}
```

Any ideas? Thank You. I'm desperate...

Answer (score 0):

I solved. Simply subtract the radius of the compass and add the result to the object you want. in my case north, east, west and south are UIImageView.

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {
    self.lblGrados.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f°", newHeading.magneticHeading];

    // Convert Degree to Radian and move the needle
    newRad =  -newHeading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        compassView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad);
    } completion:nil];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        [self.north setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-newRad)];
        [self.south setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-newRad)];
        [self.east setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-newRad)];
        [self.west setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-newRad)];
    } completion:nil];
}
```